# validacion de string unicamente alfanumericos

Tags: java

como puedo verificar si al ingresar una cadena de caracteres (String) me reconozca unicamente caracteres de tipo alfabetico junto con su salto de linea y si en caso de que se ingrese junto con numeros que me lo indique en pantalla

Comment: Usa expresiones regulares

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar [expresiones regulares](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) para validar strings.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;  

class Test {

    private static Scanner scan;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Introduce texto: ");
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        boolean alfa = Pattern.matches("^[a-zA-Z]*$", input);
        // Si son solo letras imprime "Alfabetico" si no imprime "No Alfabetico"
        System.out.println(alfa ? "Alfabetico" : "No Alfabetico"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ya lo se, que comente alonso algo y cambio la respuesta, igual puedes añadir tu la tuya.